# Accessing a Raspberry Pi Over a wifi card

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

SO, I have a wifi card (model isn't really important, can provide if needed) it supports master mode, so this is **NOT** the issue, and a raspberry pi.

I have a configured Hostapd and udhcpd on it.

Config for Hostapd:

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
driver=rtl871xdrv
country_code=US
ctrl_interface=wlan0
ctrl_interface_group=0
ssid=RDashINC-S1
hw_mode=g
channel=1
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=[redacted]
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
beacon_int=100
auth_algs=3
macaddr_acl=0
wmm_enabled=1
eap_reauth_period=360000000
```

Config for udhcp:

```
start 192.168.1.2
end 192.168.1.200
interface wlan0
remaining yes
opt dns 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2
opt subnet 255.255.255.0
opt router 192.168.1.1
opt lease 864000
```

According to udhcpd I **SHOULD** be able too access it from 192.168.1.1 while connected to it. However, when connected I get nothing from that addr, also running ipconfig it provides no gateway, nor what my IP is. So I suspect something may be awry with my configuration. Any help would make my life so much easier.

Comment: At first glance, the lease appears too high. 86400 is a day. Have you tried using wicd-curses to test?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I don't see the point of using wicd?

Comment: This is a long shot, but I wonder if it's not picking the group cipher correctly try adding CCMP along with TKIP to the wpa_pairwise.

Comment: @Spiff the issue is not that I can't connect to it, presuming your indicating that, I can connect too the internet when it's over eth0 and I'm connected to it via wifi, it just doesn't let me connect too the pi.

Comment: I use wicd just to test that the hardware is working correctly to save time - helped out when I tried using an old wifi adapter that didn't understand wpa2

Comment: So your Raspberry Pi is acting as an AP and DHCP server. Is your client machine connected to any other networks, perhaps via Ethernet? If so, is that other network on a different IP subnet?

Comment: @Spiff It's not connected to anything else.